# How To convert CameraImage from YUV420 to grayscale before passing it to tflite model

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite, grayscale, yuv

I have a tflite pre=trained model that works very good in training images(grayscale images)
but when i try it in real image i can't convert the CameraImage (from Camera flutter package yuv420) to grayscale (similar to training data) before passing to my model
is there any way to do that?

Comment: One simple procedure is Image -> Bitmap -> Grayscale (Bitmap) if you do not care for speed. I do not know though if you need then one channel Grayscale Bitmap or three channel? What is the input shape of your model?

Comment: input shape of my model is 3*3*96 (three channels) 
How can i convert my image to bitmap in flutter? is there any package?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: sadly,No till now